# Only affect pixels in buffer with alpha 0

Tags: opengl, glsl, alpha-blending

I'm working on a transition effect where I have a texture and simply draw that as a pattern to my buffer. [Here](https://99c75f36e6748a4d1f66dcdfc737c57491aa9599.googledrive.com/host/0B97j9rSYGvSsZ0ZldjNoblh2S2c/) is a demo, use "e" to start the effect again.
This looks fine but it won't work if the texture has pixels with alpha 0 < x < 1.

This is the texture I used in my demo ( zoomed ):

[image]

As you can see the edges are rough and full on opaque. If I do use a texture with softer edges the pixels with alpha will just smear the black away. How can I achieve the effect of pixels in my texture with an alpha of 0 < x 1 to only affect pixels with alpha 0 in my buffer?

Comment: Do I understand it right - you wish the circle smooth, however you do not like it gets darkened on the edges?

Comment: I do want the option for smooth edges ( so any texture can be substituted without resorting to removing soft pixels). The problem is , for example, once 2 of these circles overlap the alpha in the edges replace the black and cause an ugly alpha effect. Ill update with a picture.

Comment: Well this is awkward...Apparently I already fixed it after discovering the problem. Blending : BlendingOperation.SourceAlpha, BlendingOperation.DestinationAlpha did the trick apparently. I had this issue a while now but have only been working with hard edges. So I had no idea my problem was already solved. ACK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

( If it's more appropriate to remove this thread please let me know)

When the problem occurred I changed to hard edges and only worked with that. Meanwhile I changed my drawing logic and the fix went unnoticed:

The problem was that I didn't have the right blending modes applied, these should work. ( names might be slightly different in OpenGL)
This is done in Kha and Haxe:

```
//before rendering fading **in** blend modes : 
g2.setBlendingMode(BlendingOperation.DestinationAlpha, BlendingOperation.SourceAlpha);
//bedore rendering fading **out** blend modes :                 
g2.setBlendingMode(BlendingOperation.SourceAlpha, BlendingOperation.DestinationAlpha);
```

If someone has some pointers, that would be appreciated.